# Is it safe that when Two asyncio tasks access the same awaitable object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread-safety, python-asyncio

Simply speaking, `thread-safe` means that it is safe when more than one `thread` access the same resource and I know `Asyncio` use a single `thread` fundamentally.

However, more than one `Asyncio Task` could access a resource multiple time at a time like `multi-threading`.

For example DB connection(if the object is not `thread-safe` and supports `Asyncio` operation).

1. Schedule `Task A` and `Task B` accessing the same DB object.
2. IO Loop executes `Task A`.
3. `Task A` `await` IO operation on the DB object.(it will take long time enough)
4. IO Loop executes `Task B`
5. `Step3`'s IO operation is still in progress(not done).
6. `Task B` `await` IO operation on the same DB object.
7. Now `Task B` is trying to access the same object at a time.

Is it completely safe in `Asyncio` and if so, what does it make safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the same asyncio object from multiple tasks is safe in general. As an example, aiohttp has a session object, and it is expected for multiple tasks to access the same session "in parallel".

> if so, what does it make safe?

The basic architecture of asyncio allows for multiple coroutines to `await` a single future result - they will simply all subscribe to the future's completion, and all will be scheduled to run once the result is ready. And this applies not only to coroutines, but also to synchronous code that subscribes to the future using `add_done_callback`.

That is how asyncio will handle your scenario: tasks A and B will ultimately subscribe to some future awaited by the DB object and. Once the result is available, it will be delivered to both of them, in turn.

Pitfalls typically associated with multi-threaded programming do not apply to asyncio because:

- Unlike with threads, it is very predictable where a context switch can occur - just look at `await` statements in the code (and also `async with` and `async for` - but those are still very visible keywords). Anything between them is, for all intents and purposes, atomic. This eliminates the need for synchronization primitives to protect objects, as well as the mistakes that result from mishandling such tools.
- All access to data happens from the thread that runs the event loop. This eliminates the possibility of a *data race*, reading of shared memory that is being concurrently written to.

One scenario in which multi-tasking could fail is multiple consumers attaching to the same stream-like resource. For example, if several tasks try to await `reader.read(n)` on the same `reader` stream, exactly one of them will get the new data<sup>1</sup>, and the others will keep waiting until new data arrives. The same applies to any shared streaming resource, including file descriptors or generators shared by multiple objects. And even then, one of the tasks is guaranteed to obtain the data, and the integrity of the stream object will not be compromised in any way.

---

<sup>1</sup> One task receiving the data only applies if the tasks share the reader and each task separately calls `data = await reader.read(n)`. If one were to extract a *future* with `fut = asyncio.ensure_future(reader.read(n))` (*without* using `await`), share the future among multiple tasks, and await it in each task with `data = await fut`, *all* tasks would be notified of the particular chunk of data that ends up returned by that future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However to make me clear, to the extreme degree, is it impossible to make an object(awaitable) not safe though anyone implements the object? I think the package like `aiohttp` in your example would be safe even if there is some safety issue on `asyncio` itself because if there is, the `aiohttp` group must have considered that. Is `asyncio` completely safe, preventing from the issue(race condition) itself?

Comment: @SangminKim It is quite possible to have such a bug. A programmer could forget that `await` is a (possible) context switch and falsely rely on object state not having been modified when an `await` is crossed, where in reality another task changed it. Such things happen. But your question explicitly compared coroutine to multi-threaded code, so my answer highlighted the fundamental differences. In multi-threading, a context switch can appear anywhere, and each CPU works with its own cached copy a part of RAM, so *all* access to shared data has to be protected with locks and barriers.

Answer (score 2):

No, asyncio is not thread safe. Generally only one thread should have control over an event loop and/or a resource associated to the event loop. If some other thread wants to access it, it should do it via special methods, like `call_soon_threadsafe`.

Comment: I don't mean `multi-threading`. In spite of `single-thread`, `Asyncio` could probably access the same `awaitable` object. I am asking that case.

Comment: @SangminKim You say you don't mean multi-threading yet you use "thread" word all over the place. -.- Perhaps you should think about your question before posting it. Anyway no, you can't access the same resource anytime you want. If two async threads access the same resource then there's a race condition. It is atomic only if the entire work is synchronous. Otherwise you need some form of locking.

Comment: Sorry, If my question gave confusion, I edit it again, please read again.